# At CKAN webbrowser I cannot see datasets in list but in activity stream, is there a extra module needed?

Tags: ckan, data-harvest, oai-pmh

Using harvest oai-pmh to send metadata from dspace to ckan. I can see the files (packages) in activity stream but not in dataset list. The link in activity stream leads to data in dspace surface. also in db i see the entries for the packages. logfiles only throw warning regarding dateformat. 
Do I Need any extra modules to generate a list with datasets for ckan Webbrowser?

Comment: Have you tried re-indexing your solr?  `paster --plugin=ckan search-index rebuild --config=/etc/ckan/std/std.ini`  https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/maintaining/paster.html#search-index-rebuild-search-index

Comment: I tried re-indexing but nothing changed

Comment: No extra modules should be needed for the basic list feature. Just some random trouble shooting thoughts. Have you tried creating a dataset manually in CKAN web UI and seeing if it appears? Are the newly created datasets draft or private by chance? Have you logged in to CKAN and tried viewing them?

Comment: A dataset created in CKAN web UI appears in listing. Most of the datasets are public. I can see them in DB, there they are all listed - public and private. Although I can see  datasets harvested with dcat_rdf - in list too.